# Micronaut SPA Contoller

Tags: java, micronaut

This is very standard Spring SPA Controller.

```java
@Controller
public class SPAController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "forward:/static/index.html";
    }

    @GetMapping("/**/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String html5Mode() {
        return "forward:/static/index.html";
    }
}
```

How to do exactly the same in Micronaut? There are some answers on SO already, like this one:

```java
@Get("/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
@Secured(SecurityRule.IS_ANONYMOUS)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public HttpResponse<?> refresh(HttpRequest<?> request) {
    StreamedFile indexFile = new StreamedFile(res.getResource("classpath:public/index.html").get());
    return HttpResponse.ok(indexFile);
}
```

This is completely wrong. I "don't know" `index.html` file location, I only know its URL.

Comment: Under what scenario do you not know where the index file is?

Answer (score -2):

I don't know under what scenario you wouldn't know where the index file is, however you could make a request with the Micronaut http client to whatever URL is serving it and return that response body.